# Setting WPF datagrid source to a group of string arrays

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have number of string arrays. For example an array of 13 usernames then a seperate array of 13 passwords. Could someone please tell me what the most efficient way of getting these into a WFP datagrid is?

The simple option I can think of is to loop through the arrays, pick out the values and add them as a row into the datagrid but I was wondering if I can pass the arrays in as columns or something?

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid works on attributes (columns) and items (rows) concept. So datastructures like collection of objects, data table or XML works best for loading data ibnto `DataGrid` intuitively.

With arrays of plain value types, you would have to convert them into a data structure. Use linq for your advantage...

```
 var consolidatedList = 
     arrayUserName.Select(
           usrNm => 
             new {
                   UserName = usrName, 
                   Password = arrayPasswords[arrayUserName.IndexOf(usrName)]
                 }).ToList();

 dataGrid.ItemsSource = consolidatedList;
```

Of couse the list generation would be slow for large number of items in the arrays. In such case run a loop or use PLINQ (in case of .Net 4.0).

Comment: Followup question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010961/get-cell-values-from-a-wpf-datagrid-that-has-been-populated-with-anonymous-types)