# Get cell values from a WPF datagrid that has been populated with anonymous types

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, anonymous-types

I have a datagrid that I populated with 2 arrays of strings by following the process as outlined in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009612/setting-wpf-datagrid-source-to-a-group-of-string-arrays/13009734#13009734)

Now when Im trying to get selected cell values im struggling with pulling the cell values back out.

So far I have:

```
IList rows = dgMain.SelectedItems;
```

Which returns a list of the selected items, where the first item contains an object with the username and password.

My question is how do I access the username and password? I guess I need to cast the object in the list to something that will allow me to call `.UserName` and `.Password` on it?

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: Possible solution here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901506/cast-an-anonymous-types-in-object-and-retrieve-one-field

Comment: I'll take a look and try that out.